# How to build a parameterized query or user escaping in this SQL statement in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

```
command.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE LOGIN {0} WITH password='{1}'", loginName, password);
```

loginName and password are based on some user input

I realize that it's bad practice to do it int this way but how to avoid sql injections here?

Answer (score 8):

Call `sp_addlogin` instead - it's already parameterized

Comment: good point. are there other `sql` products that use this same syntax to create logins?

Comment: Ok, I can do it this way. Now I'm facing another problem - I need to create database. CREATE DATABASE doesn't seem feasible to be parameterized either.

Comment: Its worth noting that, the MSDN page for `sp_addlogin` has a warning that the proc will not be available in a future release of SQL server, and therefore shouldn't be used in new developments. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to parameterize your SQL.  You may also want to check out [this article on writing a DAO](http://rlacovara.blogspot.com/2010/04/aapl-part-5-how-to-write-data-access.html) that handles this type of thing. I'm not sure if you can parameterize the LoginName.  You're probably best off calling sp_addlogin like the previous poster said.

```
       command.CommandText=  @"CREATE LOGIN @LoginName WITH password=@Password";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@LoginName",
                Value = "MyLoginNameValue",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Size = 50
            });
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Password",
                Value = "MyPasswordValue",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Size = 50
            });
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work - it throws an exception "Incorrect syntax near '@LoginName'."

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the most right way to do it is to use SQL Server SMO SDK. I don't care of any other SQL engines since we'll never move from SQL Server for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize such queries by wrapping your DDL query in an `exec` as follows:

`command.CommandText = "exec ('CREATE DATABASE ' + @DB)"`

If you then add the parameter for `@DB` as usual this should work (in t-sql at least).

It should be possible to use `CREATE LOGIN` in the same fashion.

Comment: Ultimately string concatenation is still being performed, just inside the database engine, so I don't see how this mitigates against injection (e.g. `@DB = '\'1=1'`)

Answer (score -1):

Can try something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "CREATE LOGIN @login WITH password=@pwd", conn);
SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@login ";
param.Value         = usertextforlogin; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param  = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@pwd";
param.Value         = usertextforpwd;   

cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: you cannot parameterize object-names in T-SQL, and the `CREATE LOGIN` statement uses an object-name, not a string/text value for its arguments.