# Parameters supplied for object which is not a function. If the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running Windows 7 and II7 and SQL server 2008 R2 . I have an aspx program and when I try to run it I get the following error

> Parameters supplied for object 'users' which is not a function. If
>   the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is
>   required.

What I've coded is this :

```
  public ArrayList GetGoodsList(string type, string goodsType, string user, string payType, bool flag)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Conn"].ToString());

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sSql = "select count(*) from users('" + type + "','" + goodsType + "','" + user + "','" + payType + "')";
        if (flag == true)
        {
            sSql += "where IsCommend = 1";
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sSql;
        conn.Open();
        int maxRow = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        sSql = "select * from users('" + type + "','" + goodsType + "','" + user + "','" + payType + "')";
        if (flag == true)
        {
            sSql += "where IsCommend = 1";
        }
        cmd.CommandText = sSql;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        ArrayList gInfos = new ArrayList();
        GoodsInfo gInfo;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxRow; i++)
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                gInfo = new GoodsInfo();
                gInfo.G_ID = Int32.Parse(reader["G_ID"].ToString());
                gInfo.G_Name = reader["G_Name"].ToString();
                gInfo.Type = reader["Type"].ToString();
                gInfo.GoodsType = reader["GoodsType"].ToString();
                gInfos.Add(gInfo);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        return gInfos;
    }
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You should look into Parametrized queries. And possibly show the values of `type`, `goodsType`, etc. (all of the function parameters). That's likely where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to say?

Comment: Parameterized queries: [explanation of why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5468460/238722); [explains how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7197005/238722). Also note that [Alastair Pitts' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349872/238722) is on track to fixing the issue you're seeing. Parameterized queries simply help with preventing [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), plus performance, plus caching, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Without giving away the answer, your issue in in your `SELECT` statement, `sSql = ...`

It's not the correct SQL syntax.

Have a read of [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29) on the `SELECT` statement.